# Discrete math: find prime number which solves the following conditions

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

Find prime number $p$ and polynomial $f$, so that the ring $F_p[x]/(f)$:

1) contains non-zero element $w$: $w^n=0$ for some $n$

2) doesn't satisfy 1), but is a field

3) is a field which contains $8$ elements,

4) $9$ elements

I know definitions of ring and field, but I'm just starting solving examples, so I'm asking for any help how to start it.

Comment: Do you know anything about irreducible/reducible polynomials and $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field?

Comment: By points (3)-(4) it is clear this question means $\;p=2,\,3\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in terms of polynomials which are irreducible (or reducible depending on what you want) in a given field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

For example,
Consider $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$. It has $0,1,x,x+1$ as its elements (think why?). Now consider $(x+1)^2 \equiv x^2+2x+1  \equiv x^2+1 \equiv 0$ in this ring. Thus it has an element $w=x+1$ such that $w^2=0$.

Now try with a different polynomial say $x^2+x+1$ and see what kind of ring structure you will get.

Answer (score 0):

(1) For example, for any prime $\;p\;$:

$$\Bbb F_p[x]/\langle x^2\rangle\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;w:=x+\langle x^2\rangle$$

(2) For example with $\;f(x)=x\;$

For (3) you need *precisely* $\;p=2\;$ , and for (4) you have to work with $\;p=3\;$ , and in both cases you need an irreducible quadratic over the correspondent $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ . Try, for example $\;x^3+2x+1\;$ for (4), and try to do by yourself (3)